# Upgrading Azure Function From 3.1 to .Net 5 Give "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task could not be loaded

Tags: azure-functions, upgrade, .net-5

I'm trying to update Azure Function from 3.1 to .Net 5.
I am following the below article
https://codetraveler.io/2021/02/12/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/

I created a new Time Triggered Function version 3.1 and followed the above article

After completing all the required steps, rebuild gives below error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB4062 The "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task could not be loaded
> from the assembly
> C:\Users\schudasam.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.11\build..\tools\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild.dll.
> Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
> and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
> public class that implements
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  XYZ.Functions   C:\Users\schudasam.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.0.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets    38

***Tools : Visual Studio 2019***

[Visual Studio Project ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx7RZ.png)

**EDIT**

*We postponed upgrading to .Net 5.
Will leave the question here as others might have similar issue.
Wouldn't be able to try the suggestions, hope it helps others.
Thank you for suggesting solutions everyone.
Please upvote the solutions that works for you*

Comment: Could you please check if azure functions in the solution were referencing to different sdk version and if there is any misspelled tags? Also please check https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/128#issuecomment-337711852 ( Similar issue while upgrading)

Comment: @JayaChatterjee-MSFT 
I tried the github solution, didn't work, Azure function is referencing .Net 5
Currently we postponed upgrading to .Net 5.
But will leave the question here if anyone else has the issue, and someone finds a solution.

Comment: Removing the reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions seems to do the trick for me

Answer (score 13):

Indeed like Tobias was mentioning, removing below line in de csproj solved the error.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.9" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to one of my colleague, the error is pointing to a reference from dotnetcore 3.1 which is wrong, it should be referenced from dotnet 5, try doing the following in your .csproj file

Replace the following

```
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.3" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
```

with

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Analyzers" Version="1.0.0" />
```

or remove the same package from your solution explorer under the packages of your project and add it via the nuget manager.

Edit:

If you are following the article to the point then to be replaced package reference is following

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.0-preview3" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
```

Comment: Very tks @Muhammad Nauman Shaukat