# Azure Function startup's Configure not being called

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to create non-static functions in my Azure Function projet in .NET 5 (VS 2022) and the `Startup` Configure method is not being called.

Here's my start up class

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(AuthenticationGateway.Functions.Startup))]
namespace AuthenticationGateway.Functions
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup //public or not, still does not get called.
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            
            //break point here never gets hit...
            
        }

        
    }


}
```

And here's the function in question:

```
namespace AuthenticationGateway.Functions
{
    public class CreationConnection
    {
        private AuthenticationGatewayContext Context { get; set; }

        public CreationConnection(AuthenticationGatewayContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        [Function("CreationConnection")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {            

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried commenting all of the code in `Configure` just in case it was a problem with it, not working either. Also tried marking the startup class as `public` too, no go.

Here are the dependencies for the projet in question

[image]

They are not the default dependencies the projet has when creating an Azure Function projet but as I tried other solutions to fix the issue, it lead me to plug those in.

Here's what the console is saying when starting the project:

> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       3.0.3904 Commit
> hash: c345f7140a8f968c5dbc621f8a8374d8e3234206  (64-bit) Function
> Runtime Version: 3.3.1.0

Anything I missed ?

EDIT: I have reverted to the following dependencies as the previous ones made it so no functions would be found in the project.

[image]

On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) page here it says those following dependencies have to be installed:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package version 1.0.28 or later
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (currently, only version 3.x and earlier supported)
```

I have done so, except the last one because it is incompatible with .NET 5 it seems. Also, the project is now unbuildable:

```
error MSB4062: The "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task could not be loaded from the assembly
```

Comment: What happens if the class is marked as public?

Comment: @PeterBons Already tried that, no go.

Comment: What does your `host.json` look like?

Comment: And your actual function

Comment: Oh, and your settings inside Azure? I presume you mean it's not working in Azure, not on your local machine?

Comment: @Liam No this is local machine, the problem is so basic, I'm not even in the cloud yet.

Comment: Well there is nowhere near enough information here to help. I'd suggest you start afresh with a new function and add functionality gradually. It could be anything from the CLI to a coding error

Comment: @Liam add functionality gradually ? This is an already empty project. I've also said that if I remove the logic from `Configure` the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same issue which you got by following the below steps:

1. Created the Azure Functions (Stack: .Net5-v3) in VS2022.
2. Before adding `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.functions` to the project, it was built successfully.

[image]

3. After adding `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.functions` to the project, it has run to the same issue MSB4062 error as below:

[image]

By referencing these SO [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889715/upgrading-azure-function-from-3-1-to-net-5-give-generatefunctionmetadata-task) and [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889911/unable-to-compile-azure-function-v4-out-of-process-in-vs-2022-enterprise-version), removing `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.functions` will solve the compile issue.